# Replace variable in dart

Tags: flutter, http, dart

In consts class, I have declared this

**Consts**

```
static const URL = "";
```

In login bloc, after login successfully,server will return the `url` to me, and I assign the `url` to this variable.

```
Response user =
          await _repo.getLogin(context, email, password);
      var baseResponse = UserResponse.fromJson(user.body);
      if (baseResponse.status == 101) {
        Consts.URL =  baseResponse.url;
       }
```

In repo class, assume I have 5 methods, I need to use the `url` in consts class.Is it a good solution and possible?

```
Future create(){
    try{
     var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST',Uri.parse(Consts.URL));
    }catch(e){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a value to a const during run time since const is a compile-time constant.

Please refer documentation on https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const

> Final and const If you never intend to change a variable, use final or
> const, either instead of var or in addition to a type. A final
> variable can be set only once; a const variable is a compile-time
> constant. (Const variables are implicitly final.) A final top-level or
> class variable is initialized the first time it’s used.